# Add space between variable name and colon in Visual Studio Code + Typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

As someone who used UnityScript exclusively for many years, I became very used to defining variables like this:

```
var name : string = 'Bob';
```

On a Node-based project, I just started using Typescript, however I noticed that VS Code seems to want to do this instead:

```
var name: string = 'Bob';
```

How can I make it add the space between the variable name and the colon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly there's no option is VS Code itself; however, you can make the [ESLint plugin for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) your default formatter for TypeScript and use the [`type-annotation-spacing`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/type-annotation-spacing.md) rule with the following configuration:

### `.eslintrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing": [
        "error",
        {
            "before": true,
            "after": true,
        },
    ],
  }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a method to make Prettier or VS Code enforce the same rules, but I can recommend using ESLint for getting into the nitty-gritty of formating!

[More information on the TypeScript ESLint, including installation](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Install plugin of typescript([TSLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin)) in visual studio code.

Now Example to fix space or error issues.

Warning or error
[image]
**Solution**

Hover on **device**(warning) and click on Fix and you see options like -> now select **Fix-missing whitespace** and **Fix all-missing whitespace**
[image]
options
[image]

> Same way you can fix other issues like errors

Comment: Does this fix `var name: string` to `var name : string`?

Comment: Please be warned: "TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint."